# regex help - delimiters

Tags: python, regex

```
- Dropbox login fix
- Updated iris viewer
* other aspects are to be improved
+ fix crash on viewing update 
? Photos in notes now support copy, cut and paste - By long pressing a photo in a note, you can access the context
menu for copy, cut and paste of the photo. The photo can be pasted to any place in the text of notes.
Do you like the version? Please take the time to leave a review whenever you update the app.
```

I need to retrieve the sentences with the delimiters (-, *, + and some others that I use below). So looking for output like:

```
['Dropbox login fix', 'Updated iris viewer', 'other aspects are to be improved', 'fix crash on viewing update', Photos in notes now support copy, cut and paste - By long pressing a photo in a note, you can access the context menu for copy, cut and paste of the photo. The photo can be pasted to any place in the text of notes.']
```

Using a regex like:

```
r = re.split(r'(?m)\s*^[-*:;+&.?]+\s*|\.$',txt)
```

but this also returns the last line, which I don't want. This sort of free text without delimiter may/may not be present in the text I am working with.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `split` for this. Use this regex:

```
^\s*[-*:;+&.?]+\s*(.+)$
```

in `re.findall()` function to get all your matches.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL5iD3/7)

Comment: I use split because some text ends up remaining when there is a line break and white space at the end of a line but the next line still has text. I added another line to better explain above.

Comment: so how do you suggest I take care of matching multiple lines?

Comment: Can you tell me why `? Photos in notes...` line shouldn't be in output?

Comment: sorry, my bad...it should be included. I just forgot to update the output

Comment: Oh np. [But this output is what you are getting from above regex, check here](https://regex101.com/r/sL5iD3/8)

Comment: it gets truncated at this line " you can access the context..". Basically, I want everything all the way until "notes."

Comment: Now this is becoming inconsistent. What is the difference between lines starting from `menu for copy...` and `Do you like the...`. You want later line to be avoided in results but previous one to be included.

Comment: yes, because everything until "Do you like the..." is part of the "Photos in notes.." basically, in the text that I have there is white space between "context" and "menu" but essentially they are part of the same sentence.

Comment: How to know reliably at what point previous sentence is ending?

Comment: @newdev14, According to the sample text you've provided there's a `line break` between `"context"` and `"menu"`, so that would indicate it's not part of the same sentence.

Comment: one way is if there is a full stop at the end of the previous line like the one right before "Do you like the..." and the fact that there's no delimiter starting on the "Do you like the.." Would this be possible to disentangle?

Comment: Why though does your `"sentence"` have a line break in it? That seems to be the main problem now, so why not fix the improper formatting first - then split the text accordingly. There's nothing to differentiate between the line that starts with `menu...` or the line that starts with `Do...` - they both appear to be regular sentences that don't match the criteria of the previous lines.

Comment: another way would be to get everything in between the delimiters so that text spanning across multiple lines can be captured. But I don't know how easy that would be to implement. I can post another example if that helps. Thank you for your response.

Comment: is there a way to automate the process of getting rid of such line breaks. I'd assume I would need to do this manually thousands of times through the xml file I am working it.

Comment: That's the thing... if you look at the line that starts with `? Photos` it appears to be similar to the lines before it. Then the line that starts with `menu...` appears to be similar to the line below it. How would you tell the program that `menu...` belongs to `? Photos...` other than the lowercase/uppercase.

Comment: @anubhava, Nice idea, but then there's the consideration of `what if` the break was between `Context` and `Menu`...

Comment: Yes me and you have already suggested that there is no 100% foolproof way to break a multiline input into sentences like this where newline may or may not be part of each sentence.